# Set tooltip dynamically for Ext.Net button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, extjs, ext.net

I wanted to set a tooltip dynamically, when two classes get toggled. I'm pretty new to Ext.Net and jQuery/Javascript and just trying to do some stuff on my own. This is what I have so far:

```
    if (DBA.mapFilterOn) {

        btnMapFilter.removeCls("icon-filter-off");
        btnMapFilter.addClass("icon-filter-on");
        btnMapFilter.toolTip("Filtering ON");
    } else {

        btnMapFilter.addCls("icon-filter-off");
        btnMapFilter.removeCls("icon-filter-on");
        btnMapFilter.toolTip("Filtering OFF");
    }
```

The classes toggle fine. I'm not sure how to get the Ext button tooltip to show through jQuery. The code above doesn't get it to show. I know how to do it through the aspx side though. Maybe I'm writing it wrong and jQuery?

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: what exactly is `btnMapFilter` a jQuery object or an ExtJS component (which one?)

Comment: It's actually an Ext button

Answer (score 1):

there is [setTooltip()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-method-setTooltip):

```
if (DBA.mapFilterOn) {
    btnMapFilter.removeCls("icon-filter-off");
    btnMapFilter.addClass("icon-filter-on");
    btnMapFilter.setTooltip({text: "Filtering ON"});
} else {
    btnMapFilter.addCls("icon-filter-off");
    btnMapFilter.removeCls("icon-filter-on");
    btnMapFilter.setTooltip({text: "Filtering OFF"});
}
```

Comment: Ah okay! I missed that one. I'll give it a try thanks, and follow up.

Comment: That didn't work. :( Ext.net has always been a bit fidgety and buggy IMO. I did specify the ToolTipType="Qtip" on the aspx side. Anything else I need? Or the problem could be deeper with our current setup maybe. No clue. Thanks again

Comment: ok try to set a tooltip object (updated my answer with it). if that does not work, it could be something with ext.net and I won't have any clue.

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work still. Sorry for the late follow up. I'm guessing it's a weird Ext thing. No worries! Just using a static tooltip now

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **[.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)**:

```
if (DBA.mapFilterOn) {
    btnMapFilter.toggleClass("icon-filter-on icon-filter-off");
    btnMapFilter.toolTip("Filtering ON");
} else {
    btnMapFilter.toggleClass("icon-filter-on icon-filter-off");
    btnMapFilter.toolTip("Filtering OFF");
}
```

Comment: Sorry I updated my description. I don't need help toggling the classes that's working already, I need help showing the tooltip. :)